# NGINX bad gateway error when validating arrays with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have a weird problem. Everything in my app works great, including simple validation rules.

However, when I try and validate an array, NGINX is giving me a `502 bad gateway` error.

For example, this works fine:

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
    ]);
```

But this causes the bad gateway error:

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'steps.*.name' => 'required',
        'steps.*.title' => 'required',
        'steps.*.type' => 'required',
        'steps.*.answer_options' => 'nullable|required_if:steps.*.type,Question',
        'steps.*.input_type' => 'nullable|required_if:steps.*.type,Input',
    ]);
```

I've tried increasing memory limits etc. in the server config and nothing has resolved the issue...how can I correct this and ensure it won't happen on the production server?

Comment: How big is your array? Can you try submitting only one record.

Comment: Funny you should ask, if I make the array smaller I don't get the bad gateway error.

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: Are there any errors in nginx’s error log? What’s the output of the following command?
sudo tail -30 /var/log/nginx/error.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your problem only occurs if you have a large POST request. Can you try adding these to your `nginx.conf` file:

```
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
```

You may increase the values if you want, depending on how large is your POST data.

Comment: added this in the `http` section of `nginx.conf`, ran `brew services restart nginx` and it made no difference.

Comment: Just found this error - `upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream`

Comment: @kejodion, I updated my answer, kindly check my answer above.

Comment: that worked, I no longer get a `502`, but if the POST data is too large it disappears from the request completely. do you know what setting will fix this?

Comment: I think that is a `php.ini` problem, can you edit your `php.ini` and increase your `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to validate an array using Laravel v8 running valet on Mac.

I'd never seen it before, but I ended up checking my logs in
`~/.config/valet/Log/nginx-error.log` which showed `upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream`.

As mentioned in @aceraven777's answer, you need to change some nginx settings, with the following working for me:

Create `~/.valet/Nginx/all.conf` with this:

```
proxy_buffer_size   4096k;
proxy_buffers   128 4096k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   4096k;
```

Append this to `/usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`

```
fastcgi_buffer_size 4096k;
fastcgi_buffers 128 4096k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 4096k;
```

Credit goes to [@elaman on a GitHub valet issue](https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/290#issuecomment-398686133) for the steps above.

I ran `valet restart` after and my page started outputting the validation errors instead of 502'ing. You may just be able to restart nginx rather than valet as a whole, but I never got the chance to try as it worked first time for me.